# Spring boot - HttpSession is null between two different request

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, api, httpsession

**First, when I call the API "/fetch/event/1221", I am able to set the session attribute,
But I am getting httpSession as null when I call the "fetch/partcipant" API. 
How can I fix this?**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fetch/event/{eventId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public SuccessResponse<Event> fetchEvent(@PathVariable("eventId") String eventId, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
            Event event = eventService.getEventById(eventId);
            HttpSession httpSession = httpServletRequest.getSession(false);
            httpSession.setAttribute("event", event);
            return new SuccessResponse<Event>(event);
        }


 @RequestMapping(value = "/fetch/participant", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public SuccessResponse<List<Participant>> getListOfActiveParticipants(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        HttpSession httpSession = httpServletRequest.getSession(false);
        Event event = (Event) httpSession.getAttribute("event");
        System.out.println((Event) httpSession.getAttribute("event"));
        return new SuccessResponse<>(participantService.getParticipants("ALL", event.getId()));
    }
```

Comment: Are you calling the endpoints is exactly the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all , you are using `httpServletRequest.getSession(false)` in `/fetch/event/` , it will not create a session if there is no current session. Change it to `true` to force it create a new one if there are no current session:

```java
 HttpSession httpSession = httpServletRequest.getSession(true);
```

Once the session is created , it will return the session id through cookie in the response header :

```sh
< HTTP/1.1 200
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=6AD698B82966D43FF395E54F5BFCEF65; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

To tell the server to use a particular session , the subsequent request should include this session id through cookie. In case of [curl](/questions/tagged/curl), you can do :

```sh
$ curl -v --cookie "JSESSIONID=6AD698B82966D43FF395E54F5BFCEF65" http://127.0.0.1:8080/fetch/partcipant
```

which will add the following HTTP request header :

```sh
> GET /fetch/participant HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
> Cookie: JSESSIONID=6AD698B82966D43FF395E54F5BFCEF65
```

Then in `getListOfActiveParticipants()` , you should get the session that is created in `fetchEvent()`